# why document.write doesn't complete as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just trying to set up a little test page and even it doesn't behave as expected.

Given the following working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">
<title>Terry's Test Page</title>
<script src='jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>from the html in index.html</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I get what I expect, the one line from the html and Terry's Test Page in the tab label. However, if I add just before the `</head>` line:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
document.write('<p>from the js</p>');
});
</script>
```

I properly get the 'from the js' line -- no from html since document.write replaces it -- but the tab label is not filled with Terry's Test Page. In IE the tab label shows the url, in Firefox it shows 'Connecting ...' but it never gets beyond that.

What is it about document.write that I don't understand? Do I have to issue some sort of end of file or some such?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you call [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write) after page load, it calls [`document.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.open), which empties the **whole** document. The browser does its best and creates a complete new document with what you provide. The document is not only the content in the `body`, but everything else as well.

In your case, your document is `<p>from the js</p>`, but since this is not a valid HTML document (missing `html`, `head` and `body`), the browser will add what's necessary.

For example take

```
document.write('<head><title>foo</title></head>');
```

This will just create an empty `body`, but set the title of the page to `foo`.

Comment: If the document.write() call is embedded directly in the HTML code, then it will not call document.open().

Comment: @j08691: Yes, I clarified my answer.

Comment: @Felix-Kling is right here, because you put document.write() in the head before the body you essentially replace the body. You need to use it in the body of the document if you want your markup to appear there.

Comment: @davidethell: In this case it would not matter where the script is located. `document.write` is inside jQuery's `ready` handler, so it's called *after* the page was loaded.

Comment: Ah, live and learn as they say. I used

    $('<p>from the js</p>').appendTo('body');

and all is well. Many thanks.

Comment: @Terry: Yes, I'd say you hardly need `document.write` in normal use cases. You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

`document.write` is no longer widely used, especially with jQuery. You should use append or insert instead. That said, it does work, but it's not recommended: http://jsbin.com/upamem

Comment: While it's true that one has to be careful with `document.write`, this does not really answer the question.